# SwiftUI - How to align bottom edge to center of sibling

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Please have a look at this image before reading the question

[image: Please have a look at this image before reading the question]

I'm currently trying to align the red view's vertical center (/centerY) to the bottom edge of the green view in a SwiftUI View.

I'm coming from UIKit where I would solve this with something like `viewA.centerYAnchor.constraint(toEqual: viewB.bottomAnchor)`

But how would you solve this the SwiftUI way? I have kind of the following hierachy:

```
VStack {
    ZStack {
        Image("someImage")
        Text("Awesome Title") // <- align center to the Image's bottom edge
            .frame(width: 200, height: 130)

    }
    Spacer()
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found the solution:

1. Set the ZStacks alignment to `.bottom`. Now the red view will be aligned to the green views bottom edge. Thanks to @Andrew. But this is not enough:
2. Set the red views .alignmentGuide to the following:

   -> `.alignmentGuide(.bottom) { d in d[.bottom] / 2 }`

Explanation: Now the green view's bottom edge will be aligned to 50% of the red view's height! Awesome!

Answer (score 8):

If you remove the `frame` from the `text` and add a bottom alignment to the `ZStack`, it will give you the desired effect.

```
        VStack {
            ZStack (alignment: .bottom) {
                Image("someImage")
                Text("Awesome Title") // <- align center to the Image's bottom edge
            }
            Spacer()
        }
```

result:
[image: result]

Comment: But then the text’s bottom edge is aligned to the bottom edge of the image. What I want is to align the *vertical center of the Text* to the bottom edge of the Image! :)

Comment: This only aligns the bottom edge, it doesn't center it as the question asks for :)